# rest_framework and Django urlpatterns for api_root raising 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using rest_framework with Django to create the REST API for my application. But when I load the webpage (GET /api/v1/) on my browser I get a 500 Internal Server Error with the following output:

```
    AssertionError at /api/v1/
    Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/v1/
    Django Version: 4.1.7
    Exception Type: AssertionError
    Exception Value:
    Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.
    Exception Location: D:\projects\warehauser\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\permissions.py, line 208, in _queryset
    Raised during:  main.views.api_root
    Python Executable:  D:\projects\warehauser\env\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.10.6
    Python Path:
    ['D:\\projects\\warehauser\\warehauser',
     'C:\\Users\\omega\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\omega\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\omega\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\omega\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
     'D:\\projects\\warehauser\\env',
     'D:\\projects\\warehauser\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Fri, 24 Mar 2023 23:42:41 +1100
```

---

Here is my **urls.py**

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home',),
    path('api/v1/', views.api_root),
    path('api/v1/products/', views.ProductList.as_view(), name = 'product-list'),
    path('api/v1/products/<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name = 'product-detail'),
    path('api/v1/orders/', views.OrderList.as_view(), name = 'order-list'),
    path('api/v1/orders/<int:pk>/', views.OrderDetail.as_view(), name = 'order-detail'),
    path('api/v1/users/', views.UserList.as_view(), name = 'user-list'),
    path('api/v1/users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name = 'user-detail'),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework import generics, permissions, reverse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import *
from .serializers import *

# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url='/auth/login')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {},)

get_class = lambda x: globals()[x]

##
## API Views
##

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'products': reverse('product-list', request=request, format=format),
        'orders': reverse('order-list', request=request, format=format),
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
    })

class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class ProductDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class OrderDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()
```

I have tried defining and not defining the get_queryset() function for the views, and still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states the problem explicitly: `` Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method. `` You need to define either a queryset or a get_queryset method on the api_root view.

Are you just trying to return a list with links to the specific view sets? Django Rest Framework does this automatically using the [browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/). All you need to do is create a [Default Router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) in your URLs module.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately the defaultrouter needs a viewset, but I am using generics.ListCreateAPIView and generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why? DRF has comparable view sets. It wouldn’t take much to switch to them.

Comment: I have converted my views to viewsets.ModelViewSet and a DefaultRouter, and it mostly works. Except now the webpages for the api keep appending "List" to the model name. For instance: Api Root / Product List List / Product List Instance. How do I get rid of the first List from the name?

Comment: Comments won't let me add newlines but try to read this class: class UserList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'

Comment: router = routers.DefaultRouter()

Comment: router.register(r'users', views.UserList)

Comment: urlpatterns = [

Comment: path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),]

Comment: SOLUTION: I was naming the ViewSet classes as UserList. The view calls get_view_name(self) which removes "View" or "ViewSet" from the classname and returns the remainder (basically). I have renamed all my ViewSet classes to <something>ViewSet and now the page titles work.